# cocos2d particle effects not appearing

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hi All
Im just having an issue with particle effects not appearing all the time. Im coding using objective c and cocos2d for the iphone.
Below is the code in question.

```
CCParticleExplosion *emitter;

    emitter = [[CCParticleExplosion alloc] initWithTotalParticles:30];
    emitter.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"particle_bubble.png"];
    emitter.position = ccp(MidX,MidY);
    emitter.life =0.5;
    emitter.duration = 0.5;

    emitter.speed = 60;

    [self addChild:emitter];
    emitter.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    CCParticleMeteor *emitter2;

    emitter2 = [[CCParticleMeteor alloc] initWithTotalParticles:150];

    emitter2.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"fire_particle.png"];
    emitter2.position = ccp(MidX,MidY);
    emitter2.life = 0.5;
    emitter2.duration = 2;

    emitter2.speed = 60;

    id emitMove = [CCMoveTo     actionWithDuration:0.5 position:HUD.moonSprite.position ];


    [self addChild:emitter2 z:1];

    [emitter2 runAction:[CCSequence actions:emitMove, nil]];
    emitter2.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
```

This code is within the same function right after each other as shown.
but sometimes the 2nd particle effect is not created and i cant figure out why. the first particle effect is always created no problems so im sure it is getting into the function correctly but sometimes (almost 50%) the 2nd meteor emitter is not displayed. i have tried messing around with z values to make sure it is not hidden behind an other object and it doesnt appear to be the problem. Anyone have any ideas on why this would be happening?
Thanks
G

Comment: Have you tried NOT moving the second emitter?

Comment: yeah and its the same thing sometimes it appears and stays where it spawned and other times nothing at all

Comment: when i remove autoRemoveOnFinish it works everytime. anyone any ideas why that is? and how am i ment to release the emitter if i dont use autoRemoveOnFinish? if i have multiple emitters being created on the fly how can i release them without autoremoveonfinish?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the 71 squared particle designer. http://particledesigner.71squared.com/
Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Define the emitters in a local variable (.h)
2. Call this before the code above:

   ```
   if (emitter.parent == self) {
       NSLog(@"em1 released");
       [emitter release];
   }

   if (emitter2.parent == self) {
       NSLog(@"em2 released");
       [emitter2 release];
   }
   ```

   This checks if the emitter is a child and removes it, so you can remove the `emitter.autoRemoveOnFinish` so your emitter will show every time